# Removing Title From Links to Site

Tags: css, links, title

So I've been using my wordpress site to blog. I've also been importing those blogs to Medium, and anytime I share the article the site title is appended to the end. So if the article is named "100 Ways to Do Something" and I make a link to it, the link will expand and it will say "100 Ways to Do Something -- Site Title"

Even when importing the article to medium and making links to the Medium article I see it, I assume because Medium links it back to the original wordpress article.

Is there some custom css I could add to the site to fix this? I'm relatively new to web development as a whole

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying the `<title>` tag in the WordPress article includes your site title? If so, you'll need to check through your plugins and possibly the theme, as a number of things can manipulate titles. It's common for SEO plugins to add the site title to the `<title>` tag and most plugins have an easy way to turn that off.

Comment: Customizing css will not affect the title used by your browser which is taken from the <title> tag within ever page. If you are referring to the title heading when displaying an article that can be removed using custom css. Perhaps your theme has an option for how title is displayed too.

Comment: @WebElaine that might be it, but how do I check what is the title tag? I use Yoast SEO and nothing is jumping out at me, but I'm not sure what that setting would be called

EDIT: Just checked the specific blog post I made and that was definitely it, found a way to remove it. You pointed me in the right direction WebElaine, thanks!!